# Проблема с передачей объекта в функцию другого класса

Tags: c++, ооп, функции, классы

В общем, пытался передать объект в функцию другого класса.

У меня есть класс `Object`, это как бы объект на поле.  И нужно в Метод `Change()` передать объект `Field`, созданный в `int main()`.

В методе `Change()` нужно изменить переменные объекта `Field`.[image: код и ошибки:]
Но, у меня при этом возникают ошибки, и как не пробовал, ошибки одни и те же.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне это осуществить?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Object
{
    public: int x = 0, y = 0;
    public: char symbol;
    public: void Change(Field field)
    {
        field.obj[x][y] = '#';
    }
};

class Field
{
    public:char obj[20][20];
    public: Field()
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    Field f;
    Object o;
    o.Change(f);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поменяйте объявление классов `Object` и `Field` местами

Comment: До обращения к Field программа должна знать, что это такое. Если Object использует Field, то по порядку сначала должен идти Field, а потом Object

Comment: Спасибо, это реально работает.. 
А я потратил сутки : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо просто поменять местами объявления `Object` и `Field`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Field
{
    public:char obj[20][20];
    public: Field()
    {

    }
};

class Object
{
    public: int x = 0, y = 0;
    public: char symbol;
    public: void Change(Field field)
    {
        field.obj[x][y] = '#';
    }
};


int main()
{
    Field f;
    Object o;
    o.Change(f);
}
```

B заменить `Render` на `Change` :)

Но!

Вы замените при этом элемент **копии** `Field`. Если это то, что вам нужно - то вперед. Но если вы хотите менять элементы в исходном объекта `Field` - передавайте его по ссылке.

Comment: Да, я уже понял, что это копия.
Для того, чтобы работать не с копией, нужно написать Change(Field& field);

Comment: Да, именно так.